# Spring Keycloak jwt map Create At Date to Token

Tags: spring, oauth, jwt, token, keycloak

I am developing a rest api with spring boot and I use Keycloak with openid connect ( Oauth2) for my auth flow.
I want to create an endpoint for querying data. If the "from" timestmap is not set ( I declared it as optional) I want to use the data since account creation. In order to make a request to the keycloak admin rest api I would prefer to get this information from the token. 
I've had a look at the different built in scopes ( microprofile-jwt etc. ) but I can't find the specific mapper.Also google couldn't help me out.

I use Keycloak 6.0.1.
Is it possible witht his version? Or will I have to spent a rest call to the admin api?

I know I can create a timestamp in my attributes and map it in the token but if possible I want to use to auto created by keycloak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible through creating new mapper in client or scope settings.

First open mappers tab:

- For client go to `clients` - select client - `Mappers` tab.
- For scope go to `scopes` -> select scope - `Mappers` tab.

Create new mapper and fill in the following fields:

- Name - just a name for the mapper
- Type - User Property
- Property - createdTimestamp
- Token Claim Name - created_timestamp (you can use any name you like)
- Token Claim Type - long

For scope mappers you also have to assign newly created scope to the client.

After completing these steps you can get user created timestamp directly from access token.